# python dashboard slider formatting the return value

Tags: python, slider, plotly-dash

[image: Slider]
I have coded a slider and callback to do some arithmetic calculation. The layout and code as follows:

The slider is controlled by a dropdown: four values from the dropdown are used to calculate the value, which is displayed by the slider. I'm getting the value as **(211290.99000000017,)**, but I want to format the output to be in **$** and should be displayed on the right side of the slider. Currently, it is displaying on the left side of the slider.

```py
dbc.Col ( [ 
        
        dbc.Row ( html.Div ("Hello")), 
        dbc.Row ( html.Div ( 'Gross Sales' )),
        dcc.Slider(
        id='gross_sales',
        min=0,
        max= 100000,
        step=0.5,
      )
```

Call back:

```py
@app.callback(Output('gross_sales', 'children'),
             [Input('C', 'value'),
              Input('S','value'),
              Input('B','value'),
              Input('P','value')
             ])
def display_value(val,val1,val2,val3):
     if val == 'C' and val1 == 'A' and val2 == 'P' and val3 == '18' :
        val= data.groupby(['Manl'])['Sa'].sum()['P'],
        return format(val)
     else:
        return {}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Prathap

Comment: Do you have any screenshots you can include? It would be helpful if you could walk through your code in relation to the UI with pictures.

Comment: I have added the slider in that link . You can see that value which i want to be converted to $ and to be displayed at the right side end of the slider.

Comment: It's good to [embed images in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) rather than link to them.